# Determinant function theorem

Tags: multilinear-algebra

I am trying to prove the following theorem from the book of mathematical physics of Sadri Hassani

**Proposition 2.6.9**: Let $\Delta$ be a determinant function in the N- Dimensional vector space V. Let $|v\rangle$ and $\{|v_{k}\rangle \}_{k=1}^{N}$ be vectors in V. Then:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{N} (-1)^{(j-1)} \Delta (|v\rangle, |v_{1}\rangle,..., |v_{j}^{*} \rangle,..., |v_{N} \rangle)|v_{j}\rangle= \Delta ( |v_{1}\rangle,..., |v_{N} \rangle) |v\rangle$$

Where the * on a vector mean that it is missing.

I already know how to prove the proposition when i consider that $\{v_{k}\}_{k=1}^{N}$ are linearly independent. but i have not been able to prove that when it is linearly dependent, both the **LHS** and the **RHS** are 0. The **RHS** one is easy to see, as a multilinear functional is 0 when the set is linearly dependent.

However i have been stuck with **LHS**, any help or advice is well received.

Comment: +1 for citing a [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319011943) that deserves a wider audience. For the linearly independent case, this proposition is equivalent to [Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). Examine the structure of the proof to determine what to argue for the linearly dependent case.

Comment: Thanks, i did not notice that before.

Comment: I don't see how to prove the linearly dependent case using just the material shown up to that point in Hassani's book. Much more machinery is constructed in the more concrete [_Linear Algebra via Exterior Products_](https://github.com/winitzki/linear-algebra-book) by [Sergei Winitzki](https://github.com/winitzki).